# Show number of variations in WooCommerce shop page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to display the number of variations for each product in the Shop Page of WooCommerce, under the Product title, I tried the following:

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_echo_stock_variations_loop' );
        
    function custom_echo_stock_variations_loop(){
    global $product;
    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ) {
        
        foreach ( $product->get_available_variations() as $key ) {
            
             echo count($key['attributes']) . ' more variations';
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

They should return "6 more variations" and "3 More Variations" but I get 111111 and 111 instead.

[image]

How can I show array length out of the foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_echo_stock_variations_loop' );

function custom_echo_stock_variations_loop() {
    global $product;
    if ( $product->get_type() == 'variable' ) {

        echo '<br/>'.count( $product->get_available_variations() ) . ' more variations';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this code works in the builder (elementor), but the page can no longer be saved (fatal error; 500)

Code in the function.php of the child theme

```
add_shortcode( 'anzahl_varianten', function() {
    global $product;
    $variations = count($product->get_available_variations());
    return '+ '.$variations. ' weitere Varianten';
});
```